# DIV background won't stay in one place

Tags: css, background, position

Is there something wrong with my code that makes this green css div block not show up in the exact same place on each page?

On the index page it's perfect, right under the nav bar. But on the page "This" it's not in same place. The stripe also changes position with any additional content. Why is that if it's set to relative? Isn't it floating and other content shouldn't disrupt its postioning? I'm so confused. PLEASE take pity on me as I am not great at CSS as you will see from my code:

```
/* green stripe */
.stripe
{

  padding: 0.25rem 9999rem;
    background-color: #4ea647;
 z-index: 889;
  position: relative;
   top: -1200px;
  left: -500px;
  height: 50px;

}
```

THIS IS THE SITE:

https://andrea-levin-7gzp.squarespace.com/

Comment: Why not put it in the correct place? Now it's relative to something there below the point where it should be, you're setting its position with *pixels* so it will move around based on browser settings etc etc. I mean, if you want a green bar under the links, why not just stylize the actual element that is already there? *mainNavWrapper* or *mainNavigation* elements are there.

Comment: thank you sami for talking to me about this. I don't know how to stylize the actual element because its in squarespace -- so i figured out a work around (so I thought) of putting a div of color behind the nav bar -- the person I'm designing it wants a color behind the nav bar. I need the color to go 100% -- so while I can put the green color behind the nav words it doesn't stretch to fit the entire page. I already moved the nav bar down

Comment: this is the nav bar code i used but I don't know how to make the green stripe behind it go 100% #mainNavWrapper{
     text-align: right; 
  
   top: 120px;
align: left;
   background-color: none;

 }

Comment: Any guidance you can give me would be so appreciated. I'm losing it over here.

Comment: Ačiū, kad padėjai!